# Multiple tables in one layout in Bi Publisher

Tags: oracle11g, report, business-intelligence, bi-publisher

lets assume that i have a table with the below values

```
Id    Date           

1     4/10/2015      
2     4/10/2015
3     5/10/2015
```

I want to create a report Layout with multiple tables for every distinct Date.

In this case ,the output will be something like that(two tables)

Date:4/10/2015

```
 Value        
   1
   2
```

Date:5/10/2015

```
 Value
   3
```

How can i implement something like this ?
I use Oracle Bi Publisher 11g..

Answer (score 0):

Use the for-each-group

```
<?for-each:LOCATION; GROUPING-ELEMENT?>
```

For example, you'd fist group by date

```
<?for-each-group:TOP_LEVEL/LINE;Date?>
<?Date?>
Value
```

Then you can show each record.

```
<?for-each:current-group()?><?Id?><?end for-each?>
```

Finally End the group.

```
<?end for-each-group?>
```